# How correctly to put text on an image?

Tags: php, image, text

Good day.

**First add all images in one:**

```
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r1,$x1,$y1,0,0,$ww1,$hh1,$w1,$h1);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r2,$x2,$y2,0,0,$ww2,$hh2,$w2,$h2);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r3,$x3,$y3,0,0,$ww3,$hh3,$w3,$h3);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r4,$x4,$y4,0,0,$ww4,$hh4,$w4,$h4);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r5,$x5,$y5,0,0,$ww5,$hh5,$w5,$h5);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r6,$x6,$y6,0,0,$ww6,$hh6,$w6,$h6);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r7,$x7,$y7,0,0,$ww7,$hh7,$w7,$h7);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r8,$x8,$y8,0,0,$ww8,$hh8,$w8,$h8);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r9,$x9,$y9,0,0,$ww9,$hh9,$w9,$h9);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r0,$x0,$y0,0,0,$w0,$h0,$w0,$h0);
```

**In result we get image:**
[image: ssde]

**Next step - add text on image:**

```
$font = 'calibri_bold_italic.ttf';
$black = imagecolorallocate($dst_r, 255, 255, 255);
$bbox = imageftbbox(42, 0, $font, $text);
$text_x = (imagesx($dst_r) - $bbox[4])/2;
$text_y = 70;//(imagesy($dst_r) - $bbox[5])/2;
imagefttext($dst_r, 42, 0, $text_x, $text_y, $black, $font, $text);
```

**But in step two result we get image:**

[image: vvv]

***As we can see - bottom of the picture have empty strip.***

*Tell me plasse where eeror?*

*Why i get empty strip on bottom image and how delete her ?*

Comment: increase your scripts memory limit - `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use GD for this, but I would highly recommend that you use one the OO image manipulation libs, they will make your tasks sooo much simpler:

https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

https://github.com/smottt/WideImage